# Rendering Problems Exception raised during rendering: com.android.ide.common.rendering.api.LayoutlibCallback

Tags: android, android-studio

I encountered a problem when creating a project in Android Studio. (Version 1.5.1)

I describe my actions step-by-step:

- Open Android Studio.
- Create a new project without any activity.
- Make a blank activity.

And there might be a problem in preview mode:

I get this message:

`Rendering Problems Exception raised during rendering: com.android.ide.common.rendering.api.LayoutlibCallback.getXmlFileParser(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser;`

In stack trace:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.android.ide.common.rendering.api.LayoutlibCallback.getXmlFileParser(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser;
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.ResourceHelper.getInternalComplexColor(ResourceHelper.java:146)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.ResourceHelper.getColorStateList(ResourceHelper.java:231)
    at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.getColorStateList(BridgeTypedArray.java:308)
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:776)
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:705)
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:701)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView.<init>(MockView.java:50)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView.<init>(MockView.java:45)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView.<init>(MockView.java:41)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:163)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.CustomBar.<init>(CustomBar.java:95)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.StatusBar.<init>(StatusBar.java:67)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.Layout.createStatusBar(Layout.java:222)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.Layout.<init>(Layout.java:144)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:213)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:426)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:350)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:510)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:498)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:888)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:498)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.access$600(RenderTask.java:72)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:610)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:607)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.runRenderAction(RenderService.java:362)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:607)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:629)
    at com.intellij.android.designer.designSurface.AndroidDesignerEditorPanel$6.run(AndroidDesignerEditorPanel.java:480)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:320)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:310)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$2.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:254)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:269)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:227)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:217)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
    at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:351)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 414, accepted):

I had the same problem after some updates minutes ago, what I did to solve the rendering issue was to change the android version used to render layouts from Android Studio back to "API 23: Android 6.0".

[image: Android studio]

Comment: Yes, that works. Also, it's best to uncheck "Automatically pick best", as it just picks the latest one. You should manually pick the sdk you wish to preview with.

Comment: I done this but I get the following error now. `Couldn't resolve resource @android:color/background_material_light`

Comment: Just to warn: it's a recurrent problem.

Comment: But, why this problem occurs when API level set to 24. And why not in 23 ?

Answer (score 19):

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   com.android.ide.common.rendering.api.LayoutlibCallback.getXmlFileParser(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser;

Thrown if an application tries to call a specified method of a class (either static or instance), and that class no longer has a definition of that method.Normally, this error is caught by the compiler; this error can only occur at run time if the definition of a class has incompatibly changed.

Your app must target **Android 6.0 (API level 23)** to enable this behavior; you do not need to add any additional code.

Just select  **"API 23: Android 6.0"** in Preview Section .
[image]

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue when I installed android studio 2.1 on ubuntu 14.04.Even the android robot icon which displays the android version used for rendering layout was only showing API Level 24 version and no other versions.

I had to enable API 23 to be downloaded by navigating to the below path

**Tools -> SDK Manager -> Android SDK -> SDK Platforms -> Name.**

Check the Android 6.0(Marshwallow) option.This will be downloaded now.
Now you will be able to see API Level 23 and by selecting which we can get around this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with Android Studio 1.5.1 in Windows 10. The preview was not working no matter what version of Android was selected. The stacktrace starts with:

> "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   com.android.ide.common.rendering.api.LayoutlibCallback.getXmlFileParser(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser;"

When I remove the attribute `tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"`
from the `RelativeLayout` the problem resolves for all Android versions except "N".
I have Android 2.2, 2.3.3, 5.0.1 and 6.0 enabled

I can't explain why the action resolves the problem though or why it does work for version N.

Answer (score 0):

This is no timely answer but for anyone looking for anyone else experiencing the same problem an update of the android studio does the trick. While all the suggestions above work you want get update(version 2.1.2).