# AndroidStudio update destroyed everything and I need help as to which way I should rebuild (details of fiasco within)

Tags: android-studio

After this huge mess from one AndroidStudio update, am cleaning everything and starting from scratch.

I'd like to ask if anyone knows if I should go with specific versions of Java.

But first my headache, although I just cleaned my computer of AndroidStudio.

I have Win 10 64 bit
HAD AndroidStudio 1.51 (it said it was JRE:1.7.0_79-b15 amd64)

After the update I had a "Unsupported major.minor version 52.0" error

Following some posts I upgraded the Java on my machine.

First "1.8.0_74" but AndroidStudio couldn't find the JDK directory, so I installed "1.8.0_73" and AndroidStudio found the JDK directory.  But then I started getting rendering errors but with Rendering Problems Exception raised during

```
rendering:  com.android.ide.common.rendering.api.LayoutlibCallback.getXmlFileParser(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser;
```

Anyway, that's it.  This has become such a tragedy that I would rather start from scratch, but if anyone could point me as to the proper (steps) of which way I should go, I would really appreciate it.

Thanks ahead,

Sergio

Comment: Have a look at this question. It did the trick for me.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35914565/android-studio-rendering-problems-exception-raised-during-rendering-com-androi

Comment: In layout editor, change android version to use when rendering to 23 or below and try.

Comment: I did try that Sunny.  My two choices were 23.0.2 and 23.0.1.  So I picked the lower and got 4 gradle build errors of different flavors.  All for a basic no code (Hello World) app.  So am scrapping it all and trying a clean install tonight.

This is very trying....

Comment: I wiped my machine and started from scratch. Maybe that's like using a sledgehammer to squash a bug. But I just couldn't move forward.

Answer (score 4):

I met this issue when I updated the api android 23 N (preview). In xml editor, change the Api to render into Api 23 android 6.0 and Autimatically Pick best.This would solve the problem.
[image]

refer: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35914788/1233979)

Answer (score 0):

Yes.. i also faced same problem,I have resolved with changing the  version to api 23.generally it will take best/latest version ,in my case its set to N preview.