# Rendering Problems Exception raised during rendering: com/android/util/PropertiesMap

Tags: android, android-studio-2.1

I have recently updated my Android Studio to 2.1.1 and I noticed my layout previews weren't working anymore, so when I checked it showed a message saying:

> Rendering Problems
>
> Exception raised during rendering: com/android/util/PropertiesMap (Details)

When I clicked on details a message window popped up dislaying this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/android/util/PropertiesMap
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.android.BridgeContext.createStyleBasedTypedArray(BridgeContext.java:940)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.android.BridgeContext.obtainStyledAttributes(BridgeContext.java:638)
at android.content.res.Resources_Theme_Delegate.obtainStyledAttributes(Resources_Theme_Delegate.java:71)
at android.content.res.Resources$Theme.obtainStyledAttributes(Resources.java:1436)
at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:761)
at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:704)
at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:700)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView.<init>(MockView.java:50)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView.<init>(MockView.java:45)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView.<init>(MockView.java:41)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:163)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:858)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.CustomBar.<init>(CustomBar.java:95)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.StatusBar.<init>(StatusBar.java:67)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.Layout.createStatusBar(Layout.java:222)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.Layout.<init>(Layout.java:144)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:297)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:429)
at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:350)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:520)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:508)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:967)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:508)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.access$600(RenderTask.java:75)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:620)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:617)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.runRenderAction(RenderService.java:371)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:617)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:639)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.doRender(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:654)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.access$1700(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:82)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager$7$1.run(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:596)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:142)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:446)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:392)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:127)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager$7.run(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:591)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:337)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:327)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$3.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:271)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:286)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:244)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:234)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:352)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 402, accepted):

I had the same problem,and you can change your version of android to render the layouts in the preview window .

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35914565/android-studio-rendering-problems-exception-raised-during-rendering-com-androi) post:

> [image]
>
> change the android version used to render layouts from Android Studio
>   back to "API 23: Android 6.0

Comment: It does help. Just clicked the combo box in the preview window and rendered with version 23.

Comment: Jeez, does google not test ANYTHING?  This happened to me with a brand new project using ALL the default settings.  They must have only tested the latest release with Marshmallow.

Comment: So there's no way to get the N preview without this bug?

Comment: This answer solved my problem when Android Studio was trying to show the layout for API 24

Comment: @c.fogelklou It does work without any issues in Android Studio itself, which is weird.