# Error in Android Studio while rendering an XML layout

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

After having created a new project with an empty activity, the XML editor refuses to render the activity layout (Holo Light theme). The corresponding XML file is below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="utilitaires.vd63.recettes.Recettes">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and the error message is `Exception raised during rendering: com/android/util/PropertiesMap`.

The error details are below :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/android/util/PropertiesMap
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.android.BridgeContext.createStyleBasedTypedArray(BridgeContext.java:940)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.android.BridgeContext.obtainStyledAttributes(BridgeContext.java:638)
at android.content.res.Resources_Theme_Delegate.obtainStyledAttributes(Resources_Theme_Delegate.java:71)
at android.content.res.Resources$Theme.obtainStyledAttributes(Resources.java:1436)
at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:761)
at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:704)
at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:700)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView.<init>(MockView.java:50)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView.<init>(MockView.java:45)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView.<init>(MockView.java:41)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:163)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:858)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.CustomBar.<init>(CustomBar.java:95)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.StatusBar.<init>(StatusBar.java:67)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.Layout.createStatusBar(Layout.java:222)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.Layout.<init>(Layout.java:144)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:297)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:429)
at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:350)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:520)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:508)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:967)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:508)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.access$600(RenderTask.java:75)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:620)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:617)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.runRenderAction(RenderService.java:371)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:617)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:639)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.doRender(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:654)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.access$1700(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:82)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager$7$1.run(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:596)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:142)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:446)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:392)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:127)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager$7.run(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:591)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:337)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:327)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$3.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:271)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:286)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:244)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:234)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:352)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: I think this post will solve your issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37318561/rendering-problems-exception-raised-during-rendering-com-android-util-propertie

Comment: Thanks for this answer which allowed me to recover XML rendering (I change "N" to "API 23").