# Exception raised during rendering: com/android/util/PropertiesMap

Tags: android-studio

I know the question that I ask is duplicated. This issue occured after I update Android Studio to Version 2.1.1 and I startup it with JDK1.8. Just the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37318561/rendering-problems-exception-raised-during-rendering-com-android-util-propertie)

[this is the screenshot of this issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iaw8u.png)

But I don't think the answers solve this issue perfectly, because I really want to use Android N as my preview instead of using a old one.

I have updated my SDK platform and SDK Build Tools to the newest. Also I created a project whose minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion are set 'N', can't solve this issue still.

Does anyone know how to solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem. I fixed it this way.

Change your version of android to render to just ***API 23: Android API 23***

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I still confused that what the N preview is, what it's used for, why put it here.

Comment: If im not mistaken "N" is the next major version of Android. aka v7.0: https://developer.android.com/preview/index.html