# Preview in android studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

Below is the screenshot of my screen [image: preview]

> "Exception raised during rendering"

I can't see my XML preview of my project.

Please help me.

Comment: There is loads of similar issues on SO. Did you read them before asking ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rendering Problems Exception raised during rendering: com/android/util/PropertiesMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37318561/rendering-problems-exception-raised-during-rendering-com-android-util-propertie)

Answer (score 1):

If your Android Studio version is 3 or above 3 than you have to make change in styles.xml file as per below.

when you open styles.xml,you will get there:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

Make change in that file as:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

i solved my same problem like this.