# What ELSE causes this Android Studio Error?

Tags: android-studio

I'm trying to debug a layout problem in Android Studio 2.2.2 and I'm getting "*Exception raised during rendering: Binary XML file line #-1: Error inflating class* " in the Design view.

Expanding the details gives me

> ava.lang.IllegalArgumentException: fromDate: Fri Jan 01 00:00:00 EST
>   2016 does not precede toDate: Thu Jan 01 22:14:46 EST 1970    at
>   android.widget.CalendarViewLegacyDelegate.getWeeksSinceMinDate(CalendarViewLegacyDelegate.java:926)
>     at
>   android.widget.CalendarViewLegacyDelegate.access$1400(CalendarViewLegacyDelegate.java:48)
>     at
>   android.widget.CalendarViewLegacyDelegate$WeeksAdapter.init(CalendarViewLegacyDelegate.java:1013)
>     at
>   android.widget.CalendarViewLegacyDelegate$WeeksAdapter.(CalendarViewLegacyDelegate.java:1006)
>     at
>   android.widget.CalendarViewLegacyDelegate.setUpAdapter(CalendarViewLegacyDelegate.java:673)
>     at
>   android.widget.CalendarViewLegacyDelegate.(CalendarViewLegacyDelegate.java:325)
>     at android.widget.CalendarView.(CalendarView.java:115)    at
>   android.widget.CalendarView.(CalendarView.java:101)     at
>   android.widget.CalendarView.(CalendarView.java:96)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
>     at android.view.BridgeInflater.onCreateView(BridgeInflater.java:163)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:717)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:785)
>     at
>   android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:222)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:858)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)    at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:861)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)    at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)  at
>   com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:324)
>     at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:429)
>     at
>   com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:389)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:548)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:533)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:966)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:533)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$53(RenderTask.java:659)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

The screen shot looks like:
[image]

A bug like this has been discussed here:
[Rendering Problems Exception raised during rendering: com.android.ide.common.rendering.api.LayoutlibCallback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35914565/rendering-problems-exception-raised-during-rendering-com-android-ide-common-ren)

... but none of the solutions seem to work, and also the API Preview dropdown doesn't look the same -  that Stack Overflow querst5ion seemed to be for an earlier version.

I've set the API to 23, and I've also invalidated caches and restarted.

So how do I debug this so Android Studio will render my layout?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
if (isInEditMode()) {
    // do nothing or use stub
    return;
}
// do actual work
```

in method that crash. So, in preview studio will use stub, but on device application will use real data.

Comment: In WHAT method that crash?  The crash seems to be happening in the Android code, or in the Android Studio rendering code, not in my code.